# Display data after POST request without reloading page

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I have this node.js app where you can post comments on teachers profiles.

teacher.ejs

```
<!-- Form -->
<div class="">
      <form id="commentsForm" action="/teachers/<%=teacher[0].name%>" method="POST">
        <textarea class="comments" placeholder="Write here..." name="comm" id="comment" required></textarea>
        <button class="commentsButton" type="submit">Send comment</button>
      </form>
</div>

<!-- Displaying comments from database with GET request -->
<div id="commentsDiv" class="commentsDB">

  <% for(var i=0;i<comment.length;i++) { %>

    <div>
      <h5><%=comment[i].content%></h5>
          ...
    </div>

  <% } %>

</div>
```

index.js

```
// GET request (works fine)
router.get('/teachers/:name', function(req, res){

    db.query("SELECT * FROM comments", function(err, result){
        //...
        res.render('teacher', {comments: result});
    });    
});

// POST request
router.post('/teachers/:name', (req, res) => {

  const {comm} = req.body;

  db.query("INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES (?)", [comm], function(err, post){    
    // Insert correctly on DB        
  });    
});
```

The data typed on the textarea is inserted on the database but my webpage tries to reload and stays loading forever.

What I want is to show the new data inserted without reloading the page, how can I do that?

I tried inserting the new data directly with a script on teacher.ejs but it didn't work:

```
<!-- removing: action="/teachers/<%=teacher[0].name%>" method="POST" from <form>
and adding: onClick="addComment() on <button>-->
 <form id="commentsForm" >
    <textarea class="comments" placeholder="Write here..." name="comm" id="comment" required></textarea>
    <button class="commentsButton" type="submit" onClick="addComment()">Send comment</button>
 </form>

<script>
    function addComment(){

      var input = $('#comment').val();

      var newComment = document.createElement("h5");

      var textComment = document.createTextNode(input);

      newComment.appendChild(textComment);
              
      document.getElementById().appendChild(newComment);
  }
</script>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Make an ajax call to database

Comment: Isn't it better to display the data that was just sent and not interact with the database? The comments already inserted are loaded from the DB with the GET request and the new ones added on the form are shown "manually".